Building a very simple analog computer (summation and subtraction only)
First of all, I come from that other land called Mechanical Engineering where we speak in regular languages that don't have things like "op amp" and "ADC" and "NPN", etc.  So most of these posts are well beyond my comprehension.  However, I've been having this idea lately and it won't go away.
I'd like to build a super simple analog computer.  In mind I would have two Potentiometers.  Turning one knob would light up as many LED bulbs as I wanted for input 1.  Knob two for input 2.  So I imagine two rows of LED bulbs, each row 9 LEDs.  So I turn knob until 4 LEDs light up.  Other knob until 3 LEDs light up.
Then the summation would happen and a third set of LEDs (18 total in this example) would light up according to the answer.  So in the example above 7 LEDs would light up.
I'm assuming I need learn how to use ADC's and a simple summation Op Amp loop.
Would this be a beginner friendly project?  I'm not really sure where to start..
(edit) What I have: Breadboards, a 24VDC (+/-) supply, resistor assortment, some OpAmps (random), and an Arduino (for cheating while I'm figuring it out?) (/edit)

What I have:
Breadboards, a 24VDC (+/-) supply, resistor assortment, some OpAmps (random), and an Arduino (for cheating while I'm figuring it out?)

Would you be willing to just use an analog taut band meter as your display of analog values? Rather than LEDs? (The LEDs would require digitizing your analog values. And going-digital seems contra-indicated to me since you are talking about an analog computer. It also seems quite appropriate to your skill sets, as well.)

That's a good point.  So I guess I assumed that analog computers used the idea of capacitors as a ADC.. is this correct?  Because I'm kinda thinking of it as a project where I start out w/ purchased items and then potentially make own versions of said purchased items.
But I guess I am at that stage where I'm not sure what the definition of an analog computer is.. would this not be considered one?  I thought of them as a computer that doesn't use coding to get a result.

Analog computers have been around for a long time. But it really wasn't until operational amplifiers were perfected, those with sufficient precision anyway, that permitted summers, integrators, inverters, and other computational units to be fabricated and used as building blocks. Technically, that's not entirely true. There were prior mechanical differential analyzers. So I guess a lot depends upon just what tickles your fancy. Electronic (opamps) or mechanical (analyzers.) Strip chart recorders were once used, oscilloscopes later on. Anyway, you probably need to read some history, first?

There was a time when I used to just use a hand-crank machine. It would add, subtract, and could even multiply. There was no electronic power. It was entirely made out of cams, gears, etc., and powered by your arm. (Well, of course, there was also the old slide rule -- which today will cost more money than seems reasonable -- which was good with a wide variety of calculation uses.)

analogue computers do not use ADCs. You might want to start at wikipedia

@periblepsis but that arm-powered machine was a digital machine (cf. an ARM64-powered machine!)

@Neil_UK It used digital entry (huge keyboard of keys that "stuck down" when pressed) and it displayed the results as digital, too, using what looked like an old car odometer. Not sure about how "cf." references an ARM64. But I'm slow, today.

getting a row of LEDs to light to indicate the value of a voltage either involves a lot of random logic, an Arduino (you said you're not averse to some initial cheating), or there is a specialised IC LM3914 that drives a column of 10 LEDs from a control voltage, and is stackable to drive more, which would be the second easiest way. The Easiest Way would be to buy a few cheap DMMs as your  analogue readout devices. You would need at least one anyway for debugging. For a few $, you get a 3.5 digit ADC and display.

@Andrew If you ever want to just sit in stunned silence for a while, get your hands on a KSR-35 teletype and open it up. I used to use one (and I know where I can lay hands on a fully functional one in the EU, if I can arrange to ship it here). Those beasts are something where the mechanical engineer(s) involved were likely sent off to a rest-home for the remainder of their lives after creating it. It's a real piece of work to behold and attempt to understand. I spent many many hours trying.

@periblepsis I was comparing (that's cf., for compare) powered by arm, you cranking a machine, with ARM, the successful CPU design

What got me interested actually was reading that NASA had a working flight simulator that was completely analog and they used it well past the point of software and coding.  That blew my mind.
So regardless of the definition (to be honest, I am not too interested in specific definitions or movements as far as this project is concerned) I'd just like to make something cool.  So let's define it as that.  "something cool to me: Make a circuit with knobs that light up LED's.. LED's sum and the number of LED's that light up indicate the answer.
: )

I am super appreciative of the comments and I do appreciate the cool history.

Probably you'll find the LM3914 bargraph driver to be useful for your displays. (get some while they're still available)
So that just leaves the task of adding two voltages.
That's a hard task (you need an op amp), but we can cheat and instead make the average of the two voltages using a resistive divider and then turn up the sensitivity on the third display by running it with a lower reference voltage.
This isn't going to work compute in integers, if you set the two potentiometers to 4.5  you'll get 9 as the result.
On the other hand you could do a sililar device all in software in a microcontroller, then you'd be learning programming, LED matrixes and ADCs.
